# Listing and Counting Unique from Duplicates

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates, excel-2010

I have a Table with 6 columns. Column 1 has duplicates:

```
ABC1
ABC2
ABC3
ABC4
ABC1
ABC1
ABC2
ABC4
```

What I want is the following:

```
ABC1   3
ABC2   2
ABC3   1
ABC4   2
```

I want to achieve the above via VBA, and the result stored in a 2D array. I am also open to suggestions if it is not possible via VBA.

Comment: Did you made an attempt yourself? I don't see a question here.

Comment: Copy column A somewhere and [Remove Duplicates](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) then use a [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34) on the unique values.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim Dic As Object: Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dic.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    Dim Cl As Range, Data As Range, Key As Variant
    Set Data = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row, 1))
    For Each Cl In Data
        If Not Dic.exists(Cl.Value) Then
            Dic.Add Cl.Value, 1
        Else
            Dic(Cl.Value) = CLng(Dic(Cl.Value)) + 1
        End If
    Next Cl
    For Each Key In Dic
        Debug.Print Key, Dic(Key)
    Next Key
    Set Dic = Nothing
End Sub
```

output

[image]